# Xamarin Forms 5 - iOS App Icons Not Appearing

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I've create an asset catalog and filled out all the icons.

My info.plist has the AppIcons source set to AppIcon (which matches the assets name).

My file path to the asset icons in the info.plist matches the file path:

```
>   <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
>   <string>Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset</string>
```

What else do I need to set? It keeps setting the xamarin icon as the application icon.

Comment: Hi, do you refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/app-icons?tabs=windows#managing-icons-with-asset-catalogs) to follow that steps? And you could share screenshot of `Assets` folder and `Info.plist`.

Answer (score 0):

In case of complications with asset catalogs

- check csproj for duplicates and obsolete files
- check Contents.json of Asset Catalogs (the path is to find in the info.plist, in your case it's in the Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset folder)
- check the files in the Source Control Explorer